# Is there a way in Google Sheets to get a running countif with Arrayformula and from the bottom up?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following situation in Google Sheets:

[image]

[image]

I have a set of entries sorted descending with the `FALSE` option in Cell A1.
I would like to make a running `countif` in column C, considering the string in Cell B1 and with `arrayformula`.
The formula should take the sorting option into consideration so, in case I decide to sort the entries in an ascending order, with `TRUE` in Cell A1, the running countif makes the count from the top down, as it is depicted in the following picture.
[image: Screenshot 3]

Is that possible?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have an option with SCAN, instead of counting at each time, it keeps a running count, but hiding when the value doesn't match B1:

```
={"Formula";INDEX(IF(B2:B<>B1,"",
SCAN(IF(A1,0,1+COUNTIF(B2:B,B1)),B2:B,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v<>B1,a,SUM(a,IF(A1,1,-1)))))))}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Beautiful solution. Tahnks so much.